# Using IIterable

Tags: collections, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, c++-cx

The WinRT API function `DataPackage::SetStorageItems` takes a parameter of type `IIterable<IStorageItem^>^`. What I have is a single `StorageItem^`, not a collection.

I'm a bit confused as to how to create an *IIterable* collection from this, since I can't find a WinRT collection class that implements the interface. I realize that I can create my own class using *IIterable* as a base, but my guess is that there are existing classes that I'm just not seeing.

What am I missing here?

I guess this is obvious, but: C++, VS11, Win8, Metro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want [the `Vector` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441570%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the C++/CX-specific [namespace `Platform::Collections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh710418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```c
DataPackage^ package = …;
IStorageItem^ item = …;
Vector<IStorageItem^>^ items = ref new Vector<IStorageItem^>();
items->Append(item);
package->SetStorageItems(items);
```

Comment: That's it. I knew there had to be a compatible class somewhere--MS docs on this not quite up to snuff yet.  Thanks!